# Multiple Toggle Class's from single button?

Tags: jquery, class, toggle

I have the following working using the [classie](https://github.com/desandro/classie) library

```
var body = document.body,
menuLeft =  document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),
textPanel = document.getElementById( 'panel' ),
showLeftPush = document.getElementById( 'showLeftPush' ),
showLeftButton = document.getElementById( 'showLeftButton' );

showLeftPush.onclick = function() {

 classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
 classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toright' );
 classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
 classie.toggle( textPanel, 'hide' );


};
```

When you click the button with the showLeftPush ID all the other fire adding the classes given.

I just wondered if there was a simpler way of doing this just with jQuery alone and not having the bloat of the classie bits and bobs (that wont be supported soon anyway).

I'm not a jQuery guru hence why i used the classie library in the first place :(

Many thanks.

Comment: That's not a duplicate. He's asking with regard to catering for multiple class toggles. Please read the title carefully.

Comment: OP, in answer to your question. No, there is no way of toggling the class in any other 'simpler' way, what you've written is fine. Of course you could refer to the class names implicitly by storing them and toggling them for all elements that have the class name 'class-toggle' or something, but that's arguably not 'simpler' for the next developer that sits down to it. With regard to classie, simply use the jQuery `toggleClass` function: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
$('#showLeftButton').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $("#panel").toggleClass('hide');
    $('body').toggleClass('cbp-spmenu-push-toright');
    $("#cbp-spmenu-s1").toggleClass('cbp-spmenu-open');
});
```

Comment: Thank you JayMee and Cerlin Boss, thats exactly what i meant. I can diminish with the classie.js bits now, thank you.